# Pass variables from json file to Azure modules

Tags: azure, terraform

I have generated a json file which contains variables I'd like to pass down as parameters to my modules in Azure.

1. JSON file - test.json

```json
{
    "ad": {
        "NumInstances": "1",
        "VMSize": "Standard_F2"
    }
}
```

2. Main.tf

```hcl
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "service_name" {
  count                 = "<What goes here?>"
  name                  = "${var.service_name}-${count.index}"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.service_name.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.service_name.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.service_name.*.id, count.index)}"]
  vm_size               = "<What goes here?>"
  availability_set_id   = "${var.num_instances == 1 ? "" : "${azurerm_availability_set.service_name.id}"
}
```

How is this achievable?